# How to delete item in a room db with auto-generated id?

Tags: android, database, kotlin, mvvm, android-room

I have this room entity with auto-generated primary key and i think this causes the problem

```
@Entity(tableName = "savedlocations")
data class SavedLocationsEntity(

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int? = 0,

    @ColumnInfo("latitude")
    val latitude: Double,

    @ColumnInfo("longitude")
    val longitude: Double,

    @ColumnInfo("city")
    val city: String,

    @ColumnInfo("province")
    val province: String

)
```

This is not working

```
 @Delete
    suspend fun removeFromSavedLocations(savedLocation: SavedLocationsEntity)
```

these are working

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM savedlocations")
    suspend fun getSavedLocations(): List<SavedLocationsEntity>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun addToSavedLocations(savedLocation: SavedLocationsEntity)
```

Comment: So what isn't working?  We need more details.

Comment: delete function not working

Comment: What's not working?  Do you have a stack trace?  What happens?

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: in ui nothing happens but i got this in logcat: Attempt to update InputPolicyFlags without permission ACCESS_SURFACE_FLINGER  idk if this is related to it

Comment: Specifically, what happens.  Does the record not get deleted?  Why do you say it's not working.  Really, your lack of details makes it impossible to figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adding `@Query` instead of `@Delete`.

```
@Query("DELETE FROM YourTableName WHERE id = :your_id")
suspend fun removeFromSavedLocations(your_id: Int)
```

Comment: i have checked and id returns 0

Comment: If you enter the correct "id" address and table for the code I shared, the deletion process will continue.

Comment: thanks, i tried to send the id from repository but it keeps coming as 0 so I decided to put another parameter and it worked like that

Comment: Good. You ' re welcome.